# Use Linq to return a new object from a nested class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of elements that contain another list.

```
public class SiloNode
{
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public string Url { get; private set; }
    public List<NodeQuery> Queries { get; private set; }
}

public class NodeQuery
{
    public string Query { get; private set; }
    public int Seq { get; private set; }
}
```

I need to produce a new list containing all queries, with the corresponding parent url.

An example would be:

- https://www.bbc.co.uk, How old is the BBC?
- https://www.bbc.co.uk, Where can I find a guide to BBC channels?
- https://www.bbc.co.uk, How is the BBC funded?
- https://www.channel4.com, More queries about channel 4 ...

The output should be in the form of class LinkMeta.

```
public class LinkMeta
{

    public LinkMeta(string url, string text)
    {
        Url = url;
        Text = text;
    }

    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public string Url { get; private set; }
}
```

The complete list is contained in: root.Children.

The query below gives me all Query elements but I can't get back to Url.

```
var filtered = root.Children.SelectMany(x => x.Queries.Select(y => y.Query));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried lots of combinations, similar to the one added. Still no joy.

Comment: The `Url` is in the `x` variable, so `SelectMany(x => x.Queries.Select(y => new LinkMeta(x.Url, y.Query)))` would get you the `Url` and `Query` into the `LinkMeta`, if that's what you want.

Comment: @juharr - thanks - I've learnt something new today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda expressions have the same scope as the nested block. This means that the nested lambda expression still has access to the variable 'x'. So, you should be able to do the following:

```
var filtered = root.SelectMany(x => x.Children.Queries.Select(y => new LinkMeta(x.Url, y.Query));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with the below linq.

```
var filtered = (from snode in root
                      from qry in snode.Queries
                      select new LinkMeta(snode.Url, qry.Query)).ToList();
```

It will return List of LinkMeta. Hope it helps.